# How to port Zend+Doctrine2 from Wamp To Mamp

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm, mamp

I have a little app for myself on my windows machine which i want to put on my mac at work.

Both are php5.3.2 (doctrine using arraycache). On the mac via terminal i updated the schema, cleared cache and regenerated proxies.

But, it gives me these error notices:

```
Notice: Unknown: "id" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Notice: Unknown: "created" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Notice: Unknown: "modified" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Notice: Unknown: "name" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in Unknown on line 0
```

And so on for every member of the object in my view. I found this sleep notice very unfamiliar... any clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entity is being serialized. If you're storing it in session, this happens transparently, otherwise it could be somewhere in your code. See the documentation about serialization of Doctrine 2 entities, and some pitfalls:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/architecture.html#serializing-entities

You'd need to post some code to see where, or why this is happening, but the underlying reason is the serialization.

Comment: I could not pinpoint the issue, but your right, it was my proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Checks if the variables are protected and not private in the entity class

Comment: Check also if attributes of the serialized class have reference to instance having themself private attributes. To avoid unwanted attributes to be seralized, implement __sleep(): http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php